# Customizing Django auto admin terminology

Tags: python, django

I'm playing around with Django's admin module, but I've seemed to run into a bit of a bump that's more of an annoyance than an error. I have my modules setup using names like UserData and Status, so Django's admin panel likes to try to call each row in UserData a user datas and each status a statuss. Is there any way I can change the terminology so it will say, for example, Profiles instead of User Datas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` in your model's inner `Meta` class to override the values used there. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural